# Creating a Python Makefile That Creates an Executable Filer Within The Same Folder

Tags: python, unix, makefile

I am trying to make a python makefile for a program called python_program.py that creates an executable file called "python_program". I have created a makefile that when make is typed into the ubuntu terminal, it runs and outputs the contents of python_program.py. However, it is not creating the executable file "python_program" in the folder where the makefile and the program are. I am not sure where and what I am supposed to write for the executable file to be created. Could someone please direct me as to why my code is not creating this executable file "python_program". The code I have is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
all: python_program.py
        chmod +x python_program.py
        ./python_program.py
```

Here's the assignment:

> Use the file `python_program.py` to create an executable file called `python_program`. Assume that your Python `Makefile` is in the same directory as the `python_program.py`, and therefore, when you run `make` in that directory, your Python `Makefile` will create a `python_program` executable. Your Python Makefile must recreate `python_program` when `python_program.py` changes. There are several ways to approach this (since there’s nothing to compile). For instance, you can take advantage of the shebang functionality, which allows a file that can be interpreted to be executed. This requires that the file is executable (`chmod +x filename`).

Comment: You seem to assume that Python is a compiled language, like C. It is not.

Comment: @tripleee I know it is interpreted but I was told to use shebang, which allows a file that can be interpreted to be executed

Comment: That doesn't require a makefile. Just use your editor. Put `#!/usr/bin/env python3` or your local equivalent as the very first line of the file `python_program.py`. Make sure you don't use a Windows editor.

Comment: I would do that, but this is for an assignment and I am supposed to submit the makefile for this program to the autograder. I have submitted what I have now and it is failing because it does not create the executable file "python_program", but it does output the correct content for two test cases.

Comment: Also, if you want the shebangified file to be without a `.py` extension, then the answer to that is simple, too: rename it.  Or copy it to the wanted name. Or never give it such an extension in the first place.

Comment: We can't really help you because your question has some fundamental misconceptions in it. You may be misinterpreting the assignment requirements and thus asking a question that doesn't make sense. But since we don't have the assignment requirements we can't help interpret it for you.

Comment: Then you are leaving out something crucial, or the assignment is unclear. If the submission doesn't preserve the `chmod +x` permission, you can put that in the makefile. But take out the shebang from the Makefile; what you have will cause that, too, to be misleadingly labelled as Python code.

Comment: Requirements are: Use the file
python_program.py to create an executable file called python_program.

Assume that your Python Makefile is in the same directory as the python_program.py, and therefore, when you run make in that directory, your Python Makefile will create a python_program executable.

Your Python Makefile must recreate python_program when python_program.py changes.

There are several ways to approach this (since there’s nothing to compile). For instance, you can take advantage of the shebang) functionality, which allows a file that can be interpreted to be executed

Comment: Or simply copy the `.py` file to the same naoe without the extension; but then why have the `.py` file in the first place.

Comment: Part two because ran out of characters: This requires that the file is executable (chmod +x filename).

Comment: That is one convoluted assignment. Anyway, sounds like you should take out that first shebang line and then just change the commands section of the Makefile to be: `cp python_program.py python_program && chmod +x python_program && ./python_program`

Comment: @kaylum thank you much! That solved the problem perfectly. How do I choose your answer as the best one if there is no checkmark next to it to click?

Comment: @binarycoffee356 An answer has been posted that is more general than what I have given. Feel free to try that and mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really want or need a `Makefile` for this. On Unix, any text file which contains code in an interpreted language can be a script. The shebang should be the very first line of the script file itself, and then the file needs to be made executable with `chmod`, like you already know.

Further edits to the file will generally preserve these traits (obviously don't mess with the shebang line while editing) so they only need to be added once.

A common beginner mistake is editing the file on Windows, which might save the file in the wrong encoding.

Anyway, here is a simple `Makefile` which satisfies your requirements:

```
python_program: python_program.py
    python ./$< >$@
    chmod +x $@
```

Here's one which explicitly adds a shebang to the new file:

```
python_program: python_program.py
    printf '#!/usr/bin/env python\n' >$@
    python ./$< >>$@
    chmod +x $@
```

Both of these assume that `python_program.py` prints its own source to standard output.